# How to pass data from asp.net to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to display my data in pie/donut chart format.. Easiest i found over the internet is the simple google chart. However, it's not as simple as it looks.. I still stuck at passing the data to generate the chart.
Really appreciate your help/suggestions/solutions for noob like me..
Thanks in advance

I already have the data in a table format and now im trying to change the display into pie/donut chart.

This is my code to display the data.. (in table format)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td class="text-center"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tFemaleOccupied"></asp:Literal></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mix</td>
        <td class="text-center"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tMixOccupied"></asp:Literal></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Queen</td>
        <td class="text-center"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tQueenOccupied"></asp:Literal></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Suite</td>
        <td class="text-center"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tSuiteOccupied"></asp:Literal></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I plan to change to this

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div id="piechart"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is script for "piechart" using google chart

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphPageScripts" runat="server">
<script src="/assets/pages/scripts/dashboard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Room Type', 'No of Room'],
  ['Female', 'FemaleOccupied'],
  ['Mix', 'MixOccupied'],
  ['Queen', 'QueenOccupied'],
  ['Suite', 'SuiteOccupied']
]);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'Room Occupancy', 'width':'50%', 'height':'50%'};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

How to pass value "tFemaleOccupied" to 'FemaleOccupied' in data array?

Comment: Not sure about ASP.net but you should be able to inject echo your asp data inside JavaScript by converting it to JSON (not sure how you do that in Asp but for instance in php you do this with `var x = <?= json_encode($data) ?>;`. The other option is to use Ajax.

Comment: How are you setting the values for the ASP Literal controls right now?

Comment: @Mytharael .. its just query from DB , some calculation and pass to the parameter
    '// Total Status by Room Type
            tFemaleOccupied.Text = totalOccupiedF.ToString();'

Comment: @jcubic can u show simple code to pass data thru Ajax.? I've been google and search for easier sample and still not working..

Comment: I just need to change the data presentation from the normal table into pie/donut chart :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things you're missing here:

- The `arrayToDataTable` function expects actual data like numbers for your graph, but you're not passing it any.
- In your table, you're setting values through ASP.NET code behind.  This is server-side code, i.e., it executes on the server before the page is sent to the browser on your machine.  The Google Charts library you're trying to use, however, is a JavaScript library, so its code executes on the client side, i.e., in your browser after the page is sent to you.  In ASP.NET Web Forms, exchanging data between the server side and the client side outside of ASP.NET controls is not always straightforward.

Without changing your code too much, here's one way to make this work:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom: 0; display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td>Female</td>
        <td class="text-center"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tFemaleOccupied"></asp:Literal></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mix</td>
        <td class="text-center"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tMixOccupied"></asp:Literal></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Queen</td>
        <td class="text-center"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tQueenOccupied"></asp:Literal></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Suite</td>
        <td class="text-center"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="tSuiteOccupied"></asp:Literal></td>
    </tr>
</table>    
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; margin-bottom: 0;">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div id="piechart"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load google charts
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    // Draw the chart and set the chart values
    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Room Type', 'No of Room'],
        ['Female', <%= tFemaleOccupied.Text%>],
        ['Mix', <%= tMixOccupied.Text%>],
        ['Queen', <%= tQueenOccupied.Text%>],
        ['Suite', <%= tSuiteOccupied.Text%>]
        ]);

        // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
        var options = { 'title': 'Room Occupancy', 'width': '50%', 'height': '50%' };

        // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

This assumes you have `tFemaleOccupied.Text` etc. set in the `Page_Load` method in your code behind, or before.

A cleaner way to write this, as someone else mentioned in the comments above, is to get the data for your chart using Ajax, but that would also require you to come up with a way to serve that data (e.g., web service), which you probably don't have right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it display nicely.. thank youuu..  I'm surprise.. It's quite easy.. just add iin the <%= %> only..  Thank youuu